# PHP glob select 2 folders

Tags: php, file, directory, glob

How can I get a listing of all files from multiple folders using the PHP `glob()` function?

Something like this: `glob("data/['folder1', 'folder2']/*");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in [the documention for `glob`](https://www.php.net/glob), you can expand `{a,b,c}` to match `a`, `b`, or `c` as long as you use the `GLOB_BRACE` flag.

```
glob("data/{folder1,folder2}/*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: this only lists "folder1" contents and ignores the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to specify subdirs then Try:

```
$all_files = glob("{data/*/*}", GLOB_BRACE);
```